# Replace unknown numeric value within binary file on command line

Tags: regex, bash, text, sed

I'd like to replace some unknown values within a directory of binary files. Some, but now all the the files in the directory contain (mid way through a line) something like the following.

"myValue":"65"

I'd like to be able to modify them all to something like

"myValue":"57"

I don't know the initial value as it's different in each file but I'd like them all to be the same. I guess i'm going to need sed with regex but I'm absolutely useless with regular expressions.

Comment: Don't use sed on binary files. It appends a newline if there isn't one already.

Comment: @jthill Free BSD sed does. But GNU sed doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how:

```
cd directory
gsed -i 's/"myValue":"[0-9]\+"/"myValue":"57"/g' *
```

(following jthill's & andlrc's comments, i use `gsed` instead of `sed`.)